# Get-Content or "{ $_ - " is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, powershell, batch-file

I am trying to replace a word (USERNAME with testing) inside my file.

I am trying to run following command from powershell but I am getting error ->

**Get-Content is not recognized as an internal or external command**

```
   get-content file.text | %{$_ -replace "USERNAME","testing"}
```

I replaced the command with following:

```
powershell.exe -Command file.text | %{$_ -replace "USERNAME","testing"}
```

Now I am getting error -> **{ $_ -  is not recognized as an internal or external command**

Also tried adding **C:\Windows\System32** in environment variable but no luck.

Stuck & Need Help!

Comment: write `foreach` instead of `%` and see if that works. I guess you have a little batch/powershell mixup. `%` in batch is recognized as a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you are running below command in cmd.exe (regular command-line) as `is not recognized as an internal or external command` is an error you would see in cmd.

```
get-content file.text | %{$_ -replace "USERNAME","testing"}
```

As for your second command, there is a qouting mixup there. The easiest way to fix it would be to replace double qoutes with single qoutes and have double qoutes around the -Command parameter arguments. Just like that:

```
powershell.exe -Command "Get-Content file.text | %{$_ -replace 'USERNAME','testing'}"
```

Comment: Now after adding quotes I am getting this error

At line:1 char:39
+ ... Content file.text | {$_ -replace 'USERNAME',
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContains
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline

Comment: I am running it in powershell

Comment: Can you paste the exact command you are running?

Comment: SET CONFIG_FILE_NAME=file.conf

Comment: powershell.exe -Command "Get-Content C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\ne\w-alertshipperWSO2.conf | foreach-object {$_ -replace '_USERNAME','testing' } | Set-Content C:\Users\Admin\workspace\w-alertshipperWSO2.conf -Force"

Comment: This command is only changing 1 value how to change multiple values in a file

Comment: @MikiJay `Get-Content test.txt | % { $_ -replace 'foo','bar' } | Set-Content test2.txt`

Comment: To be honest, I do not see nothing wrong with your command and it should replace all values.

Comment: Try `(Get-Content .\test.txt) -replace '_USERNAME','SOMETHING ELSE' | Set-Content -Path .\test.txt`